# Why is a deleted aged-away question kept as aged away?

Tags: discussion

I noticed a very peculiar behaviour of Stack Overflow that I don't understand very well, I have more than one question that I reported as too broad, off-topic, etc. That sooner or later were deleted (I'm not sure if by robots or the users), for example:

- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50188934/mobile-legend-account-joined-with-this-gmail*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53116884/how-to-disable-browser-back-button-in-vuejs*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51670803/xamarin-sqlite-table-storing-in-google-drive*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50246674/jwordpress-joomla-or-durpal-which-one-should-i-be-using-for-creating-a-web-appl*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50228294/voice-wake-up-feature-when-the-device-at-screen-off-or-at-idle-mode*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128526/root-android-user-agent-change*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49957451/i-am-trying-to-write-an-ascii-program*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872841/unable-to-install-salib*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662252/keycode-is-always-229-in-chrome-for-android*

And all of them stayed as **"aged away"** in my history:

[image: Aged away]

[image: Deleted]

Could I know what is the logic behind? Since all of them were deleted/closed, shouldn't be them counted as helpful flags (if they were done by the robots or moderators)?

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I expect that when it's aged away, it's simply no longer tracked. As for the details though, hopefully someone knows more than me to help answer your question.

Comment: Hi @DavyM, I understand the part of not being tracked anymore, but they shouldn't stay in the history in my opinion, a notification could be valid that it was closed.

Comment: *deleted by Community♦ 16 hours ago (RemoveAbandonedQuestions)
This question was automatically deleted. [Please see the help center for more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)* for your first example link and that goes for most of the others as well. Only the last example question was self-deleted by the OP. It needs 5 close voters to mark your flag helpful. If in 14 days that didn't happen your flag ages away. That a question gets deleted later on, doesn't need to be related to your flag.

Comment: A question can be deleted by OP or Community without restrictions, neither of which imply the question is closed. You don't need to worry about flags that are marked as "aged away" though, they don't affect you negatively (as in they don't contribute to a flag ban)

Comment: Only one of those questions was closed before it was deleted. It might have been closed in a second round of voting, after your flag aged away. If a question gets deleted before it is closed, I believe the close flags age away rather than being marked useful.

Comment: A question with no votes and no answers automatically gets deleted after a year.  If you would have downvoted it then it would have been deleted after a month and you wouldn't have had to flag it 5 times.  Votes are better.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, thanks for your answer, I understand your point, but I still believe they should be deleted from my history or anyone else, shouldn't be? It's more like an improvement point of the platform. I'm not complaining if I reported it 5 or 10 times.

Comment: To answer the question directly: because mods can't change the result of the past flags. Also, because it reflects the flagging *history* and its result (as audit trail for mods/SE staffs when needed). It doesn't really make sense if you suddenly got 5 helpful flags from raising a single flag. (On the other hand, every 10 helpful flags increase your flag count by 1, so it's also open to be abused and/or confusion)

Comment: Hi @AndrewT., sorry, but I don't get the connection or your answer. What is the relation of 10 flags per 1? I didn't speak about it.